# Understanding the time complexity of nested while loops in a solution to count distinct pairs with given sum from geeks for geeks problem in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'd like to check my understanding of the solution of a G4G problem (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-pairs-with-given-sum/).  The problem is to determine the time complexity of the code below which counts the distinct pairs of numbers that have a specific sum. I'm not a CS major but trying to learn.

I understand the Array.Sort(arr) by itself takes O(nlogn) on average. I'd like to understand the complexity of the nested while statements.

If the equality "arr[i] + arr[j] == K" is never true, then the inner while loops are never hit and
the complexity should be O(n).

But if the equality is true, then the i and j pointers move closer whether or not there are duplicates (which trigger the inner while loops). Meeting the equality condition causes the outer while loop to move closer to its termination condition of i < j because i,j and moved closer together.

My guess would be that the entire block containing the inner and outer while loops is O(n). I don't know if I am correct and I'm not sure how to prove it. I would like some help understanding how to prove the time complexity for this problem in detail.

```
// C# program to implement
// the above approach
using System;
class GFG{
 
// Function to count distinct pairs in array whose sum equal to K
static int cntDisPairs(int []arr,int N, int K)
{
     
    
    int cntPairs = 0;              // Stores count of distinct pairs whose sum equal to K
    Array.Sort(arr);              // Sort the array
    int i = 0;           // Stores index of the left pointer  
    int j = N - 1;      // Stores index of the right pointer
 
    // Calculate count of distinct pairs whose sum equal to K
    while (i < j) 
    {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == K)  // test if sum of current pair is equal to K
        {
            while (i < j && arr[i] == arr[i + 1])   // traverse to avoid consecutive duplicate array elements
            {
                i++; 
            }
 

            while (i < j && arr[j] == arr[j - 1])    // traverse to avoid consecutive duplicate array elements
            {
                j--; 
            }

            cntPairs += 1;      // Update cntPairs
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else if (arr[i] + arr[j] < K)               // test if the sum of current pair less than K
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j--; 
        }
    }
    return cntPairs;
}
 
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = {0, 0, 300, 400, 50, 50, 500, 600, 700};
    int N = arr.Length;
    int K = 100;
     
    Console.WriteLine(cntDisPairs(arr, N, K));
}
}
```

I can understand the complexity of a single while loop or nested while loops over some dummy index, but I haven't seen a problem where the while loop conditions were basically identical and incrementing the parent loop variables during the inner loops.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, the overall time complexity is O(n). The key observation is that no matter what paths are taken through the code, `i` is incremented and `j` is decremented until they meet. So the total number of increments/decrements before the outer loop terminates is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

For time complexity proof it is enough to note that

1. For each pair `(i,j)` some constant number of operations are performed, before either `i` or `j` changes.
2. `i` starts at `0` and is always incremented, `j` starts at `N-1` and is always decremented, and on `i = j` the loop breaks. Therefore, no more than `N` different pairs `i, j` are analyzed in this loop.

So, this implies that a total number of operations performed is always less than `N` multiplied by some constant, which means the complexity is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can re-write this main loop into a single simpler loop without fundamentally changing the behaviour. Which makes the time complexity more obvious.

```cs
    while (i < j) 
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] || arr[i] + arr[j] < K)
            i++;
        else if (arr[j] == arr[j - 1] || arr[i] + arr[j] > K)
            j--;
        else {
            cntPairs++;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```